# Nvidia Denoising

Tags: cycles-render-engine, denoise

I came across the "D-noise" Git project for nvidia cards and wanted to give it a shot. On their Homepage they state that it is supported from GTX 700 cards upwards, but is already included in the newest Blender version 2.82. When checking the article on Blenders Homepage it says that only Optix on RTX cards are supported. Both GPUs I have available (GTX 970 and Quadro M4000) don't get listet under the Optix panel in Blender.

How can I get the nvidia AI Denoising running on my cards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official Nvidia Denoising is only available for RTX cards. The D-noise addon does not use Nvidia's latest hardware acceleration tools to denoise. You can download the old D-noise addon or use the build-in Intel-denoiser in the compositor to denoise your images with non-RTX cards!